# 2d cartesian plane transformation, mapping from one plane to other

Tags: python, math, graphics2d, coordinate-transformation

If you have 4 points (xi,yi); 1<=i<=4
And you want to transform them like projective transformation to new points (Xi,Yi), how do you do it?

It can be done with matrixes... Refer here for indepth explanation [transformation for css](https://franklinta.com/2014/09/08/computing-css-matrix3d-transforms/)

I just answered the question myself so yeah...I hope that it helps somebody.

Comment: I can think of about an infinite number of ways to do it. You'll have to be a bit more specific about what you want.

Comment: This is a coding website. What is your specific question? What language are you working in? You have tags for python and java...

Comment: It was not a question. I just asked about a topic to answer it myself, don't you have any other thing to do other than dislike people.

Comment: I downvoted to show my disapproval of the question and answer, viewed through the standards for this site. Please see [ask] for more information. My goal is not to cause offense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def derive_transformation_matrix(points, mapped_points):
    # Create the matrix A for the linear equations
    A = []
    for i in range(len(points)):
        xi, yi = points[i]
        ui, vi = mapped_points[i]
        A.append([xi, yi, 1, 0, 0, 0, -ui * xi, -ui * yi, -ui])
        A.append([0, 0, 0, xi, yi, 1, -vi * xi, -vi * yi, -vi])
    
    # Convert A to a numpy array
    A = np.array(A)

    # Perform Singular Value Decomposition to solve the linear equations
    _, _, V = np.linalg.svd(A)
    H = V[-1] / V[-1, -1]

    # Reshape H to a 3x3 transformation matrix
    H_matrix = H.reshape((3, 3))

    return H_matrix
```

```
def apply_transformation(matrix, x, y):
    # Create the homogeneous point (x, y, 1)
    point = np.array([x, y, 1])

    # Perform the transformation using matrix multiplication
    transformed_point = np.dot(matrix, point)

    # Convert the transformed point to Cartesian coordinates (u, v)
    u = transformed_point[0] / transformed_point[2]
    v = transformed_point[1] / transformed_point[2]

    return round(u, 8), round(v, 8)  # Rounding to 8 decimal places
```

Give 4 points as source and destination

```
# Given points and mapped_points
points = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, -1), (0, -1)]
mapped_points = [(0, 0), (2, 0), (2, -2), (0, -2)]

# Derive the transformation matrix
transformation_matrix = derive_transformation_matrix(points, mapped_points)

# Given point (x, y)
x = 32.5
y = 32.5

# Apply the transformation to get the new coordinates (u, v)
point = np.dot(transformation_matrix, [x, y, 1])
point /= point[2]

# Round the transformed coordinates (u, v) to 8 decimal places
u, v = round(point[0], 8), round(point[1], 8)

print(f"Original Point: ({x}, {y})")
print(f"Transformed Point: ({u}, {v})")
```

Comment: This is not a great way to approach the problem. `np.linalg.lstsq` will give you an answer in a much more vectorized manner.